# Fast euclidean distances between two sets of points with missing values in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two numpy matrices X and Y representing each a set of points in some d-dimensional space. I would like to compute all the euclidean distances from each point in X to each point in Y. [scipy provides the function cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) to do exactly this, but there is a catch: some points include missing values in the form of NaN. I would like the distance operation to ignore NaN entries, for example if I'm computing the distance between the following two points

```
a = [1, 3, nan]
b = [2, nan, 4]
```

then I would ignore the second and third dimensions, thus getting a distance of `sqrt((1-2)**2) = 1`.

Unfortunately in this setting cdist just returns a NaN distance whenever a single NaN is found in a pair of points. The same goes for the [euclidean_distances function in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html)

Of course one could write a double loop to perform all the required operations, but since X and Y are large matrices this turns out to be too slow. Therefore, a solution based on numpy/scipy would be ideal.

numpy does include some mechanisms such as [masked arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) that allow performing operations ignoring NaN values, but scipy seems to ignore those masks.

What would be an efficient way to perform this operation?

Comment: Add sample data?

Comment: How do you want it to "ignore" the `nan` data?  Just don't include that dimension (eeek)?  Replace it with something?  Predict it?

Comment: It really depends on the number of `nan` and the size of the matrix. A distance matrix is roughly just as efficient to calculate in numpy as with cdist. If you have mostly `nan` then you could consider sparse matrices.

Comment: @DanielF exactly, I won't include a dimension in the calculation if I find a nan there. Just added an example showing this. I'm aware this breaks the whole "euclidean distance" idea, but it works for my problem because I need to find points that are almost equal for all known values.

Comment: @user2653663 I would say around a 25% nan is quite common in my data. I didn't think about sparse matrices, will try that next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the suggestion from @Daniel F, you can use cdist like this:

```
cdist(XA, XB, lambda u, v: np.sqrt(np.nansum((u-v)**2)))
```

For instance:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, squareform

a = np.array([1, 3, np.nan])
b = np.array([2, np.nan, 4])

print(np.sqrt(np.nansum((a-b)**2)))
```

**Output:**

```
1.0
```

The example above is just to demonstrate the effect of the lambda function.

Comment: I didn't realize you could provide a lambda function as distance to cdist. Nice! I'm going to accept this answer, as it covers also the broadcasting part, which was not straightforward to me.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way is to use the standard euclidean distance formula, but replace the `sum` with [`nansum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html)

```
np.sqrt(np.nansum((X - Y)**2))
```

I doubt you're going to get anything easier than that (you'll have to work out the broadcasting yourself as you only gave 1d inputs).  Standard practice is that `nan` is always carried through calculations.

Comment: @EthanT that's . . . what the asker wanted.

Comment: Derp. Deleted my comment.